# Go Serve static files , contents with router

Tags: go

I am trying to serve static files which include javascript , css , html files

But it is failing to load all the external files in `static` directory

What did I do wrong?

Please help me

```
router := httprouter.New()

handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
  type Page struct {
    Title string
  }
  tp := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/main.html", "templates/base.html"))
  tp.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", &Page{Title: "AAAAA"})
}

router.Handle("GET", "/", handler)
// func (r *Router) Handle(method, path string, handle Handle)
// func (r *Router) Handler(method, path string, handler http.Handler)
// func (r *Router) HandlerFunc(method, path string, handler http.HandlerFunc)

router.Handle("GET", "/aaa", aaa.aaaHandler)

router.Handle("POST", "/aaa_01_submit", aaa.aaa01Submit)
router.Handle("GET", "/aaa_01_run", aaa.aaa01Run)

http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
```

Here's my files

```
/app
    /templates
        main.html
        base.html
    /static
       /js
           files to read...
       /lib
       /css
main.go
```

Comment: What url are you trying to `GET` to for a static file? (i.e. http://localhost:8000/static/index.css).

Comment: should `http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))` be `router.Handler("GET","/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is on these lines:

```
http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))
http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
```

The first line registers the static file handler with the [default mux](http://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux).  The second line runs the server with the root handler set to `router`. The default mux and the static file handler registered with it are ignored.

There are a two ways to fix this:

- Configure `router` to handle the static files using [ServeFiles](http://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router.ServeFiles).

  ```
  router.ServeFiles("/static/*filepath", http.Dir("static"))
  ```
- Register `router` with the default mux and use default mux as the root handler. Also, add a trailing "/" to "/static" to serve the entire tree and [strip the "/static/" prefix](http://godoc.org/net/http#StripPrefix) for the file server.

  ```
  http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
  http.Handle("/", router)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
  ```

These suggestions assume that you are serving the static resources using the URIs like "/static/js/example.js".  If you are using URIs like "/js/example.js", then you need to register each of the directories in static individually.

Comment: I just added file structure. Thanks